# Can't clear float after horizontal list

Tags: list, forms, radio-button, css-float

I'm creating a form and have a set of radio buttons displayed horizontally using float to save space.  However, I can't clear the float afterwards and the heading below the radios ends up right besides them.

The html code is as follows:

```
<div class="choice">

<ul>

<li><label for="yes">Yes</label><input type="radio" name="newsletter" id="yes" value="yes"/></li>
<li><label for="no">No</label><input type="radio" name="newsletter" id="no" value="no"/></li>

</ul>

</div>

<h2>Questions or Comments</h2>
```

And my CSS is as follows:

```
.choice ul li label {width: 30px;}

.choice ul li {float:left;}

.choice {clear:both;}
```

The output looks like this (asteriks representing radio buttons here):

```
Would you like to subscribe to our newsletter?

Yes * No * Questions or Comments
```

Comment: Did you want to show the h2 content in next line..?

Comment: Yes I would like it to be on the next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
h2 {clear:both;}
```

Tried the above and it seemed to work.

Answer (score 1):

I tried with a [sample](http://tinkerbin.com/kAtAwAqX) by clear left for choice div.
Changed `.choice` style like bellow,

**CSS:**

```
.choice:after {content:"#"; visibility:hidden; clear:both;}
```

Check [sample](http://tinkerbin.com/kAtAwAqX) is this useful to you.

Comment: Looks good in firefox and opera but in IE (i'm using IE 9) the h2 is still on the same line as the radio buttons.

Comment: other [solution](http://tinkerbin.com/w7x8lTvx) is applying celar:left to h2 tag.

Answer (score 0):

You use this style code

```
.choice ul li {clear:both}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the clear code.

HTML:

```
<div class="choice">

<ul>

<li><label for="yes">Yes</label><input type="radio" name="newsletter" id="yes" value="yes"/></li>
<li><label for="no">No</label><input type="radio" name="newsletter" id="no" value="no"/></li>

</ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<h2>Questions or Comments</h2>
```

CSS:

```
.choice ul li label {width: 30px;}

.choice ul li {float:left;}

.clear {clear:both;}
```

Cheer..............